# How to flag duplicate questions of another which has no marked answer?

Tags: support

As far as I can see this question is not answered at all.

Currently I am unable to flag the questions

- [Android SDK Manager does not ask for proxy password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519251)
- [Not able to update Android SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30566628)

as duplicate of question [Download API 21 on Android Studio : SDK Manager doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580430)

On the other hand they have the same issue in common (proxy not correctly accessed) but they are describing different impacts (ask for proxy credentials vs. use of proxy vs. misleading error message).

1. Flagging the questions is impossible because there are duplicate question but no one with an marked answer
2. Voting makes no sense because the questions are for different impacts (ask for credentials vs. use proxy vs. misleading error message)
3. answer / link to answer is deleted by a moderator with impossible demand to vote/flag the question or members which demand me to leave only a comment providing me a link to the board rules which do not contain any paragraph describing this guideline (BTW: I call both destructive, rude behavior)

So how can someone
1. answer correctly one question and
2. flag the questions as duplicate and
3. lead other users to the correct answer?

Comment: Without voting on one of the answers on the dupe target, you can't.

Comment: And how can I make the moderator aware of that fact and give all questioners an answer which will not be deleted as soon as I post them?

Comment: Well, meta is a good start.  Or why not make a community wiki canonical Q&A pair that covers the cases covered in the each question that have the same solution/resolution?

Comment: What is the problem exactly with voting on one of the answers?  You can always remove your upvote after the question has been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: The problems are the moderator and the stackoverflow-system. Please read the last paragraph of the post and my first answer again! Then have a look to the linked stackoverflow-question! Answers and links are deleted by Moderator. Second it is not allowed to mark the stackoverflow-questions as duplicate and lead a user to the solution as long as the solution is not marked as solution - even if it is the only solution available. So there is no way to lead users from 2 questions to the correct solution given by the 3rd question.